# Is there be a difference between ab testing on localhost and hostname?

Tags: linux, apache, benchmarking, load-testing, web-traffic

I test my website using `ab` as `ab -n 10000 -c 1000 http://example.com/path` and I got response as `160 #/second`. But when i test it as `ab -n 10000 -c 1000 http://localhost/path` the response is totally different `1500 #/second`.
why?

Answer (score 2):

Normally you should not be running load generator (`ab` or any other tool) on the same host where application under test lives as load testing tools themselves are very resource intensive and you may run into the situation when application under test and load generator are struggling for the same CPU, RAM, Network, Disk, Swap, etc.

So I would recommend running `ab` from **another** host in your intranet, this way you will be able to get more clear results without aforementioned mutual interference. Remember to monitor baseline OS health metrics using [vmstat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vmstat), [iostat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iostat), [top](https://linux.die.net/man/1/top), [sar](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sar), etc. on both application under test and load generator side - it should give you more clear picture regarding what's going on and what is the impact of the perceived load.

You may also want to try out a more advanced tool as `ab` has quite limited load testing capabilities, check out [Open Source Load Testing Tools: Which One Should You Use?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/open-source-load-testing-tools-which-one-should-you-use) article for more information on the most prominent free and open source load testing solutions (all listed tools are cross-platform so you will be able to run them on Linux)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I'm wondered why this big difference in numbers?

Comment: and about load testing tools, I was running it from my laptop and I found that the network affect badly on the test, that's why I'm using ab now.

Comment: You should be considering transport-level metrics like [connect time](https://varvy.com/performance/tcp-connection-time.html), [latency](http://blog.performancevision.com/eng/earl/links-between-latency-throughput-and-packet-loss), etc. That's why I recommending switching to more "advanced" tool which can measure and report these metrics as well, see [this example](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-analyze-results-load-test-using-blazemeter-0) demonstrating latency being the bottleneck

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, you are testing the same website in 2 different configurations:

- http://example.com/path, which is testing the remote website from your local computer,
- http://localhost/path, which is testing the a local copy of website on your local machine, or being tested directly in the machine where the website is hosted.

Testing your remote website involves the network connection between your computer and the remote server. when testing locally, all the goes through the loopback network interface which is probably several orders of magnitude faster than your DSL internet connection.

Comment: I test the same website from the same server. I test my site from my server. but by http://example.com once and by http://localhost

Comment: Then it's possible that dns resolution slows down the process, but I would expect ab to cache the DNS record, instead of querying it at each request.